# Determining stability of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, stability-theory

Determine wether the differential equation is stable or not for the following conditions:

$x'''(0) = x''(0) = x'(0) = x(0) =0$

$\frac{d^3x(t)}{dt^3}+\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}+4\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+4x(t) = e^t(H(t)-H(t-3))$

Now, I got that the solution to this differential equation reduces x(t) by use of Laplace Transforms, however, how do I determine whether or not it is stable?

$x(t) = 0.1e^{-t} + 0.1e^t - 0.1\sin(2t) + 0.1e^3 (\sin(2(t-3)) + e^{-t+3}-e^{t-3})*H(t-3)$

Now I first thought I would look at it graphically and I used Matlab software to get a plot as shown below:

[image]

And from the plot above it clearly appears to diverge (though this is not a proof).

Anyone have an idea as to an elegant proof to show the solution is unstable?

Anyone help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes your absolutely right, I fixed this, my apologies!

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the final value theorem cannot be applied?

Comment: As t becomes large, your solution should look like the linear combo of exponentials (EDIT: and some sinusoids).  I'm willing to bet there is an error in your implementation.  Are you using ODE45 to numerically solve the ODE?

Comment: I think he uses the solution formula in the plot and gets horrible cancellation errors of size $e^{100}·10^{-16}\simeq 10^{43-16}=10^{27}$ due to the two separate $e^t$ terms. Combining them to $0.1·e^t·(H(t)-H(t-3))$ should improve the graph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stability inquiry of $x(t) = 0.1e^{-t} + 0.1e^t - 0.1\sin(2t) + 0.1e^3 (\sin(2(t-3)) + e^{-t+3}-e^{t-3})\times H(t-3)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994584/stability-inquiry-of-xt-0-1e-t-0-1et-0-1-sin2t-0-1e3-sin2t)

Answer (score 1):

You have eigenvalues $-1,2i,-2i$ and no forcing after $t=3$. This is stable, but not asymptotically stable, i.e., solutions do not shrink to zero, but they also do not grow.

As you found, the homogeneous solution, which is valid for $t>3$, is
$$
x(t)=c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)+c_3e^{-t}
$$
where the first two components stay bounded while the third converges towards zero.

---

### On the graph

That a formula represents a stable solution does not automatically mean that the evaluation of that formula is numerically stable. Indeed, for large $t$ the floating point evaluation of that formula reduces to the evaluation of $0.1·(e^t-e^3·e^{t-3})$ which can incur cancellation error of the size $0.1·e^t·10^{-16}$ which for $t=100$ gives the magnitude $10^{-1+43-16}=10^{26}$ which is indeed also the scale factor in the graph.

One needs to explicitly switch off this exponential factor via
$$
0.1·e^t·(H(t)-H(t-3))
$$ 
or a similar form of conditional evaluation.

Comment: Yes but the graph shows it is unstable since it will increase infinitely no?

Comment: Also I can see those eigenvalues you got from the roots of the characteristic equation but how do you know this means it is stable?

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct eigenvalues? How did you get them? Is one of the eigenvalues not 1 therefore making it unstable?

Comment: Sorry, got lost between brain and keyboard, it is $-1$, not $0$.

Comment: To comment on the graph you would need to document how you obtained it.

Comment: "That a formula represents a stable solution does not automatically mean that the evaluation of that formula is numerically stable." what do you mean by this? surely this is a contradiction?

Comment: LutzL the plot is just a plot of x(t), I used matlab to code the function and plugged in values of t from 1 to 100 and thats what it looks like.

Comment: Look at the new section in the answer, what you are seeing is magnified floating point noise. -- BTW, there is a sign error in the $x(t)$ formula.