# Stability inquiry of $x(t) = 0.1e^{-t} + 0.1e^t - 0.1\sin(2t) + 0.1e^3 (\sin(2(t-3)) + e^{-t+3}-e^{t-3})\times H(t-3)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, stability-theory

Determine if $x(t)$ is stable, where $x(t)$ is a solution to the differential equation:

$x'''+x''+4x'+4x = e^t(H(t) - H(t-3))$

and x(t) is defined as:

$x(t) = 0.1e^{-t} + 0.1e^t - 0.1\sin(2t) + 0.1e^3 (\sin(2(t-3)) + e^{-t+3}-e^{t-3})\times H(t-3)$

How do I approach this? Do I use eigenvalues? If so, I get 2i, - 2i and 1, is that correct and what do these values imply?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok what is your intuition for that? How do you know this would cause an initial spike in the solution and the become periodic?

Comment: "..., the eigenvalues tell you a rapidly decreasing $e^{-t}$ and the imaginary ones tell you of trig functions $cos2x$ and $sin2x$" where does that come from?

Comment: Ok sorry, I am not familiar with this, why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47825/discussion-between-user2250537-and-moo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponentially growing terms can (and should) be combined to 
$$
0.1·e^t·(H(t)-H(t-3))
$$
so that it is plainly visible and also true under numerical evaluation that this term only contributes on the interval $[0,3]$.

All other terms are bounded or even decaying, so that the function is stable in a signal context and represents the stability of the zero solution of the homogeneous equation.

---

PS: The eigenvalues are $-1$ and $\pm 2i$.

Comment: But when I graph it I get a graph which seems to diverge to infinity and negative infinity - is my x(t) incorrect?

Comment: As I said in the (your? a colleague of yours?) other question, what you see is floating point noise that comes from the imperfect cancellation in $0.1·(e^t-e^3·e^{t-3})$ which are the dominating terms for larger $t$. The size of the error at $t=100$ is $0.1·e^{100}·10^{-16}=2.5·10^{26}$.